# Sql multi-foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am planning a notifications table. A user can follow another user, like/comment on a post, like/reply to a comment. However, I am stuck trying to figure out a way to have a universal pointer to the parent row. The notification table could look like the following:

```
id  |  sender_id  |  receiver_id  |  type  |  post_id  | comment_id
```

`post_id` and `comment_id` are respectively the row which the sender has interacted to. These have `on cascade delete` on them so when they are deleted, the notification also is deleted. Issues arise when I have to archive the notification because the notification sender has decided to remove comment/reply or unlike post/comment. I could add columns for that like:

```
id  |  sender_id  |  receiver_id  |  type  |  post_id  | comment_id  |  src_comment_id  |  src_reply_id
```

But looks like this is hard to scale. I could have notifications from various sources as the system grows.

I found someone on Stack using another method:

```
id  |  sender_id  |  receiver_id  |  type  |  table_id  | table_name
```

This would be hard to maintain for deletions it seems. Or are there easier methods to make this work?

Comment: You can inherit your tables from one base table (even if it has only 1 column -
 e.g. the primary key) and make them use a single SEQUENCE generator for their primary key. Then point your foreign keys to this base table